# Can't add images to my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to require an image like this:

```
const img = require('Flag');
```

And it just fails.

This is my webpack.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    alias: {
      Game: 'app/components/Game.jsx',
      Board: 'app/components/Board.jsx',
      Row: 'app/components/Row.jsx',
      Cell: 'app/components/Cell.jsx',
      Flag: 'app/components/flag.png',
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.png']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        },
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=25000'
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

Comment: Well, how does it fail?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "Flag"

Comment: You need to use the actual file name and include the relative path. If the file is in the same directory and named `Flag.jpg`, that would be `require('./Flag.jpg')`.

Comment: still the same..